# Issue with Array assignment

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having an issue with outputting an array. When I output each element without a `for` loop, the program runs fine. When I try to output with a `for` loop, the program crashes the first time I set an element in the array. I have marked the line where the program crashes when I uncomment out the `for` loop. My sort seems to work fine and the program is crashing way before that, so I'm pretty sure that isn't the issue. Any ideas why the 2nd `for` loop would crash the program at the specified line?

```
int main()
{
   int* Array;
   int j = 5;
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
   {
       Array[i] = j; //Crashes here with 2nd for loop uncommented
       cout << Array[i] << endl;
       j--;
   }
    Array = insertion_sort(Array);

    cout << Array[0] << endl;
    cout << Array[1] << endl;
    cout << Array[2] << endl;
    cout << Array[3] << endl;
    cout << Array[4] << endl;



   /*for(int k=0; k <5; k++)
   {
      cout << Array[k] << endl;
   }*/


}
```

Comment: Using an uninitialized pointer never works well.  That's why the *new* keyword exists.

Comment: well for this, it's better to just declare as an array instead of a pointer -- as in, int Array[5];

Comment: @thang This line `Array = insertion_sort(Array);` will fail to compile if `Array` really was an array.

Comment: @jon, you're right, but that line, while syntactically correct, is probably riddled with bugs.  How does it know how big the array is?

Comment: I have since modified that function to send the size. The reason I didn't in the first place is because I was using a fixed size for testing reasons. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the pointer before initializing it. You should change

```
int* Array;
```

to

```
int* Array = new int[5]; // There are 5 ints in my array
```

and make sure to

```
delete[] Array;
```

at the end, or even better:

```
int Array[5]; // This way you don't need the new keyword, so you won't need to delete[] later
```

Comment: Yeah. that fixed it. Just seemed weird that it worked without the 2nd for loop as I had it. Stupid error on my part, but weird bug to try to fix if you don't notice that, like me. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, errors like this can be hard to spot because undefined behavior sometimes looks like it's working, even when it's not!

Answer (score 1):

Right now, your array is not instanciated. It's just a pointer. You need to choose how large of an array you want before you can start writing to it.

```
int* Array = new int[5];
int j = 5;
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    Array[i] = j; //Crashes here with 2nd for loop uncommented
    cout << Array[i] << endl;
    j--;
}
```

Comment: Why does the program run fine without the 2nd for loop then?

Comment: @JoeBradish Because sometimes bugged program run correctly. Your program has *Undefined Behaviour* which means exactly what it says.

Comment: Okay, I fixed the issue. I was very confused why the for loop was making it crash at another for loop. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If this helped you come to the solution, please mark it as answered, so others with this problem will know where to look.